# map inherited DTO to Entity

Tags: java, spring, mapping

I have RestController that accept inheritance DTO:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RealTimeEventDTO.class, name = "real-time"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ScheduledEventDTO.class, name = "scheduled")
})
public class EventDTO {

    private Long id;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RealTimeEventDTO extends EventDTO {

    private EventTriggerDTO eventTrigger;

    @Builder
    public RealTimeEventDTO(Long id, EventTriggerDTO eventTrigger) {
        super(id);
        this.eventTrigger = eventTrigger;
    }
}
```

I have same structure in Domain. And I need map DTO to Entity.

```
 private Event toEvent(EventDTO event) {
        return null;
    }
```

How Can I map inherited DTO to Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/), it's useful to map entities and dto properly

**Event.java**

```java
public class Event {
    private Long id;
    private String content;

   // constructor, getters, setters, toString etc.
}
```

**EventDTO.java**

```java
public class EventDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String payload;

   // constructor, getters, setters, toString etc.
}
```

**IEventMapper.java**

```java
@Mapper
public interface IEventMapper {

    IEventMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(IEventMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "payload", target = "content")
    public Event eventDTOToEvent(EventDTO eventDTO);
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**Usage**

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventDTO eventDTO = new EventDTO(123L, "Hello World !");

        Event event = IEventMapper.INSTANCE.eventDTOToEvent(eventDTO);

        System.out.println(event);
        System.out.println(eventDTO);

    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Event {id=123, content='Hello World !'}
EventDTO {id=123, payload='Hello World !'}
```

Comment: Consider adding an example for the OP use case so that your question is more complete and useful ;) Thanks!

Comment: Edited ! Thanks @JoãoDias for advice :)

Comment: How does is taking care of inheritance..?